# Change css from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I have this CSS code:

```
.bar .progress-line.html span {
  width: 78%;
}
```

How can I change the width from javascript? I have tried many ways like

```
$(".bar .progress-line.html span").css("width", "10%");
```

But nothing is found.

I also tried this:

```
$(".bar .progress-line.html span").css("width", "10%");
```

but nothing happens.

Original example: https://codepen.io/Prashal9499/pen/oNWzPqR

Comment: Need to see the relevant HTML as well. One way you could do this is to edit your question to include a stack snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: this is the example, and i have take the first line ! or wich is better to edit from javascript ! https://codepen.io/Prashal9499/pen/oNWzPqR

Comment: Your code works. (And your two examples are the same.) Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/1171702) what you mean?

Comment: you need add library cnd jquery, after then you code jquery :$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".html span").css("width", "20%");
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to change the text, see the link in my comment to your original post.

You can do it manually like this:

New class:

```
.progress-line.html span.change::after {
    content: "55%";
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".progress-line.html span").css("width", "55%");
$(".progress-line.html span").addClass("change");
```

Comment: In the code from codepen, i want can change the widht from javascript, i have tried you example add the new class in css, and try change from java with jquery but nothing happen ! :-\

Comment: Make sure you use the settings in the JS section and *add jQuery*.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Sirec/tz2L7hrd/3/ tested it here ! :((

Comment: jQuery is not included until you add it under settings (*Resources* in jsfiddle).

Comment: Oh yes works thanks you very much, and the text how i can change it  ?

Comment: Answer is above -- but only manual. If the percentage is always changing, it's complicated. See the link I put in your original question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set a comma in between the class names while targeting multiple elements. Here is an updated version of what you have done so far.

```
$(".bar, .progress-line, .html, span").css("width", "10%");
```

Comment: This is not the same selector as what the OP uses. It'll modify other elements unrelated to the original CSS.

Comment: You definitely don’t want to change all spans… you’re making a global statement